# ruby geocoder gem with a polymorphic resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, polymorphic-associations

I've a bunch or addresses which belong to various other resources via polymorphic association

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

and my resource, lets say its a Hotel

```
has_one :address, :as => :addressable
```

I can search my address data no problem, find every address in a 20 mile radius of my search string for example

```
@addresses = Address.near(params[:search],20, :order => :distance).page params[:page]
```

I'm really struggling to join the resource i.e. the hotel info, I can link through to a details page, but I'd like to show the name of the hotel in my results for example.

I thought using :include may have helped thus:

```
@addresses = Address.near(params[:search],20, :order => :distance, :include => :hotel).page params[:page]
```

.. but no luck

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Stew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I figured it out with a little help from a colleague

```
 @addresses = Address.where(addressable_type: 'Hotel').near(params[:search],20, :order => :distance).includes(:addressable).page params[:page]
```

Hope it might help someone else!

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from you success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

In your Address model, I would define the relation with the Hotel model

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :hotel, -> { where(adresses: {addressable_type: 'Hotel'}) }, foreign_key: 'addressable_id'
```

Like well explained in this answer, [Eager load polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)

Then, like explained in the geocoder doc https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue
I would find hotels by location doing the following:

```
Address.near(generic_address, radius, :select => "addresses.*, hotels.*").joins(:hotel)
```