# How to eager load a nested polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager load a nested polymorphic association. I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is my model setup:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end

class User
  has_many :comments, as: :ownable
end
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Post.includes(comments: :ownable).to_a
```

But it's throwing this error:

```
ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError - Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :ownable
```

How can I do eager load this nested polymorphic association?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eager load polymorphic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)

Answer (score 2):

First of all your post has_many comments should also be set :as => ownable

```
    class Post
      has_many :comments, as: :ownable
    end
```

Be even after changing this, you'll still get the same error since rails cannot find a table ownable.

There is a work around posted here [Eager load polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)