# How to avoid n+1 queries when using polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 4 models, let's say:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
end    

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
  has_many :products
end

class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

So, the query `Photo.all.includes(:photoable)` works.

But if I use `Photo.all.includes(photoable: :products)` only works if all loaded photos belongs to Company. If the relation contains photos of users and companies, this error is raised:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Association named 'products' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?):
```

This occurs because user hasn't relationship with products.

Is there any way to eager load **users and companies with products** for a relation of photos?

**EDIT:**

**This question isn't duplicated of [Eager load polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)**. As I commented below, in this question I want to do eager load for polymorphic associations which has different associations(one has products and the other don't). In that question, the OP uses wrong names for table names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eager load polymorphic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)

Comment: @phoet in this question I want to do eager load for polymorphic associations which has different associations(one has products and the other don't). In that question, the OP uses wrongs names for table names.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but does `Photo.all.includes(:user, company: :products)` work?

Comment: No @ptd, because `photo` does not have `user` or `company` association. It has `photoable` association

Comment: i don't think that this is supported by rails. you would have to create n joins, one for each type of "photoable".

Comment: @Rodrigo, did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

Rails 6 added support for this case, now nested associations are only preloaded if they are defined for the object, you can even mix associations from different classes:

```rb
Photo.all.includes(photoable: [:products, :posts, :some_undefined])
```

Full runnable example:

```rb
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(!ENV['SKIP_INSTALL']) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  # rails 5 gives the error, run with RAILS5=1 to see
  gem "activerecord", ENV['RAILS5'] && "~>5.0" || "~>6.0"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:photos){|t| t.references :photoable, polymorphic: true }
  create_table(:users)
  create_table(:companies)
  create_table(:products){|t| t.references :company }
  create_table(:posts){|t| t.references :user }
end

# --- Models:
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
  has_many :posts
end    

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# --- Test:

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    2.times{    
      Company.create!.tap{|company|
        company.products.create!
        company.create_photo!
      }
      User.create!.tap{|user|
        user.posts.create!
        user.create_photo!
      }  
    }
  end

  def test_association_stuff
    rel = Photo.all.includes(photoable: [:products, :posts, :some_undefined])
    arr = rel.to_a # fetch all records here

    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.extend(Module.new{
      define_method(:debug){|msg|  raise "should not log from now on" }
    })

    assert_kind_of(Product, arr.first.photoable.products.first)
    assert_kind_of(Post, arr.last.photoable.posts.first)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add specific associations to `Photo` model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :user, -> { where(photoable_type: 'User' ) }, foreign_key: :photoable_id
  belongs_to :company, -> { where(photoable_type: 'Company' ) }, foreign_key: :photoable_id
end
```

After that you may preload nested specific associations:

```
photos = Photo.all.includes(:photoable, company: :products)
```

With access to records like this:

```
photos.each do |photo|
  puts photo.photoable.inspect
  puts photo.company.products.inspect if photo.photoable_type == "Company"
end
```

This approach loads `company` association twice, but does not do n+1 queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Should be

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

And then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues, and have found a solution.

You can call the eager load after the find :

```
photos = Photo.all.includes(:photoable)
photos_with_products_association = photos.select{|p| p.photoable.is_a?(Company)}
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(
  photos_with_products_association,
  :products
)
```

... or more generic

```
photos_with_products_association = photos.select do |p|
  p.class.reflections.keys.include?(:products)
end
```

Comment: This solution selects all photos from database before loading the `products`. So, I'm looking for an way to do this in only one query with JOINS.

Comment: 2 queries isn't bad... Avoiding n+1 should be your concern.

Comment: When bazillion photos are returned in the first query - having N+1 may better, if there's pagination

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange your are joining companies to your photos and not the other way around. Why would you do that? And do you really need those company products in the view or controller?

```
SELECT * from photos
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = photos.photoable_id AND 
                        photos.photoable_type = 'User'
LEFT JOIN companies AS c ON c.id = photos.phottoable_id AND
                        photos.photoable_type = 'Company'
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.company_id = c.id
```