# How to solve this N+1 query for 2 associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `comment.user` and I'm using the following code to populate comments:

```
@comments = Post.find(params[:post_id]).comments.hash_tree(limit_depth: 3)
```

Now, [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) shows:

> `N + 1` Query Detected
>
> `Comment => [:user]`
>
> Add to finder: `:includes => [:user]`

Now, I tried `Post.includes(:comments, :user)`, `Post.includes(comments: :user)` and other such variation, but the Bullet keeps informing me that the N+1 query persists.

Models and associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

What would be the solution?

Comment: show your models and associations

Comment: @emaillenin I've included it now

Comment: @emaillenin https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree

Comment: can you also give the list of SQLs that were generated with that hash_tree command?

Comment: @AmitJoki maybe the level of query is not where you think it is, cloud be in the model somewhere which pull the data before the place you look for.

Comment: @matanco The call stack showed me the line where `comment.user` was there.

Comment: @emaillenin `hash_tree` is just a way of showing the comments in a tree like structure. I highly doubt it's doing a separate SQL query than what's already available.

Comment: Post.includes(user: [comments: :user]) try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to include `user` at the wrong place. What bullet says is that the relation `comments` -> `user` is causing the problem.

have you tried:

```
@comments = Post.find(params[:post_id]).
  comments.includes(:user).hash_tree(limit_depth: 3)
```

Comment: I had tried this already but just didn't include it in my question, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@comments = Comment.where(post_id: params[:post_id]).hash_tree(limit_depth: 3)
```

If need user information

```
@comments = Comment.where(post_id: params[:post_id]).joins(:user).select("*, users.nickname as user_nickname").hash_tree(limit_depth: 3)
```