# ActiveRecord nested query for scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, querying

Here is my scheme:

I have

```
parcelas belongs_to pagamento
pagamento belongs_to :pagavel, polymorphic: true 
pagavel belongs_to :agencia
```

Now I want to create a scope in Parcela that would look like

Parcela.from_agencia(agencia_id) and that would query only the Parcelas that belong to pagamento that belong to pagavel that belong to this agencia_id.

Comment: You can chain together a bunch of scopes? So define a scope for each of these individual queries.

Comment: How would you suggest that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `scope` with `joins` in parcela.rb:

`scope :from_agencia, ->(agencia_id) { joins(pagamento: :pagavel).where(pagavels: {agencia_id: agencia_id}) }`

Comment: Hey there, thans for answering, I did: Parcela.includes(pagamento: :pagavel).where(pagavels: {agencia_id: 1}), and got  Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :pagavel

Comment: Missed `polymorphic` in your scheme, if you really need it, use this workaround  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic