# Using includes with nested polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, polymorphism, rails-activerecord

I am working on a Rails 5 project and have a model called Upvote that is polymorphic and belongs to either an Event or Suggestion. I am trying to specifically grab upvotes that belong to one category or the other as well as the user id of whoever created the event/suggestion, but am struggling because of the polymorphism. There was [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic) on this a few years ago, but when I tried implementing the technique it didn't work. Specifically, I added this code to my Upvote model:

```
belongs_to :suggestion, -> { where(upvotes: {idea_type: 'Suggestion'}) }, foreign_key: "idea_id"
```

but when I try something like

```
Upvote.includes(:suggestion).last
```

in the console I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "upvotes"
LINE 1: SELECT "suggestions".* FROM "suggestions" WHERE "upvotes"."i...
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

On Rails5, `belongs_to` has an `required: true` clause by default...
So, it always checks if the counter parts exists... and there is no `has_many :upvote` relation on `Suggestion`...

To don't require the counter part, you can add the option `optional: true` to your `belongs_to` clause

```
belongs_to :suggestion, -> { where(upvotes: {idea_type: 'Suggestion'}) }, foreign_key: "idea_id", optional: true
```

**OBS1**

I started a Pull Request on Rails recently just because of this question, and on [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28206#discussion_r103298460) we figured out that actually if you don't want that a `belongs_to` would be `required: true` by default, you can just config that behaviour setting the config:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

That on fresh installs of Rails5 is set to true, but is not set for apps that where migrated to Rails5

Comment: Thanks - is it OK to add the has_many on the polymorphic module itself? That is not my error I don't think unless this line has to be on on Suggestion rather than the Upvotable module that is included in Suggestion `has_many :upvotes, as: :idea, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Only if you scope it for the `idea_type == 'Suggestion'` but you still need the belongs_to scoped... or the upvote will raise errors when trying save upvotes for type Event