# has many relationship for polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
class Sample
  has_many :pictures
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :sample
end


class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

What should be the association to get all product or employee of a given sample.
`Sample.first.pictures.map(&:imageable)`. I want to get it as an activerecord association.

Comment: I think this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic

Comment: How are products/employees related to a sample?

Comment: You are missing the other side of the relation between `Sample` and `Picture`. There must be a `belongs_to: :sample` in your picture class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround:

```
class Sample
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :imageable_employees, through: :pictures, source: :imageable, source_type: 'Employee'
  has_many :imageable_products, through: :pictures, source: :imageable, source_type: 'Product'
end
```

#### Usage:

```
sample = Sample.first
employees = sample.imageable_employees
products = sample.imageable_products
```

...see [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-.through-association)

#### Explanation:

> Sample.first.pictures.map(&:imageable). I want to get it as an activerecord association.

... is I don't think it's possible, but you can still get them all as an Array instead. The reason is that there is no table (model) that corresponds to the `imageable` association, but that it corresponds to ANY model instead, which complicates the SQL query, and thus I don't think it's possible.

As an example, consider the following query:

```
imageables_created_until_yesterday = Sample.first.something_that_returns_all_imageables.where('created_at < ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)

# what SQL from above should this generate? (without prior knowledge of what tables that the polymorphic association corresponds to)
# =>  SELECT "WHAT_TABLE".* FROM "WHAT_TABLE" WHERE (sample_id = 1 AND created_at < '2018-08-27 00:00:00.000000')

# furthermore, you'll notice that the SQL above only assumes one table, what if the polymorphic association can be at least two models / tables?
```

### Alternative Solution:

Depending on the needs of your application and the "queries" that you are trying to do, you may or may not consider the following which implements an `abstract_imageable` (a real table) model for you to be able to perform queries on. You may also add more attributes here in this `abstract_imageable` model that you think are "shared" across all "imageable" records.

*Feel free to rename `abstract_imageable`*

```
class Sample
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :abstract_imageables, through: :pictures
end

class Picture
  belongs_to :sample
  has_many :abstract_imageables
end

# rails generate model abstract_imageable picture:belongs_to imageable:references{polymorphic}
class AbstractImageable
  belongs_to :picture
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :abstract_imageables, as: :imageable
  has_many :pictures, through: :abstract_imageables
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :abstract_imageables, as: :imageable
  has_many :pictures, through: :abstract_imageables
end
```

#### Usage:

```
sample = Sample.first
abstract_imageables = sample.abstract_imageables

puts abstract_imageables.first.class
# => AbstractImageable

puts abstract_imageables.first.imageable.class
# => can be either nil, or Employee, or Product, or whatever model

puts abstract_imageables.second.imageable.class
# => can be either nil, or Employee, or Product, or whatever model

# your query here, which I assumed you were trying to do because you said you wanted an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object
abstract_imageables.where(...)
```