# Rails 5.2 eager load polymorphic nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to eager load polymorphic nested associations? How can I `include` `doctor_profile`'s for `Recommendation`'s and `patient_profile`'s for `Post`'s?

I'm able to call `Activity.includes(:trackable).last(10)` but not sure how to include the associated models past there. I've tried `belongs_to :recommendation, -> { includes :patient_profile, :doctor_profile}` with no luck

```
class Activity
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

end

class Recommendation
  has_many :activities, as: :trackable
  belongs_to :doctor_profile

end

class Post
  has_many :activities, as: :trackable
  belongs_to :patient_profile

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with respect referenced [this SO answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124295/938947) 
for your problem you can managed with foreign_type field from polymorphic table to reference which model that use it

```
class Activity
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  # below is additional info
  belongs_to :recommendation, foreign_type: 'Recommendation', foreign_key: 'trackable_id'
  belongs_to :post, foreign_type: 'Post', foreign_key: 'trackable_id'
end
```

and you can call it

```
Activity.includes(recommendation: :doctor_profile).last(10)
Activity.includes(post: :patient_profile).last(10)
```

**Activity.includes(recommendation: :doctor_profile)** means

- Activity will join recommendation with foreign_type and trackable_id
- and then from recommendation will join doctor_profile with doctor_profile_id

Comment: thanks. is it possible to do the includes in 1 call?

Comment: you can try it first, I edited my answer to add some explanation about includes in one call

Comment: you can. thank you - `Activity.includes(recommendation: :doctor_profile, post: :patient_profile).last(10)`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works, but the use of `foreign_type` isn't actually supposed to do what the commenter intended.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

`foreign_type` is used to specify the name for the column which determines the class type for the relation.

I think the intended result here is to instead use `class_name` to specify which table the relation is referring to. If the relation has the same name as the table, then `class_name` can actually be inferred (which is why the provided answer works in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the above answer to work, specifying `inverse_of` for the `belongs_to` and adding for the `has_many` associations got everything to work. For example:

```rb
class Activity
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  # below is additional info
  belongs_to :recommendation, foreign_type: 'Recommendation', foreign_key: 'trackable_id', inverse_of: :activities
  belongs_to :post, foreign_type: 'Post', foreign_key: 'trackable_id', inverse_of: :activities
end
```

On the `Post` model:

```rb
has_many :activities, inverse_of: :post
```

On the `Recommendation` model:

```rb
has_many :activities, inverse_of: :recommendation
```