# Eager Load Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-5.2

PLEASE HELP! REMOVE DUPLICATE STATUS!

I know this was marked as a duplicate, but I do not think the other postings address my issue, please help explain what I am missing or address my current issue.

Thank you!

SOLUTION NOT RESOLVED FROM OTHER POSTINGS

Based on this [Eager load polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic)
I tried

#### Listing Model

```
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :car, foreign_type: 'Car', foreign_key: 'listable_id'
  belongs_to :truck, foreign_type: 'Truck', foreign_key: 'listable_id'
  belongs_to :bike, foreign_type: 'Bike', foreign_key: 'listable_id'
```

AND TRIED:

#### Listing Model

```
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :car, -> { where(listings: {listable_type: 'Car'}) }, foreign_key: 'listable_id'
```

But got the same error!

This post shows that it should work:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations

But it does not.

ORIGINAL POST:

Need to query all listings that belong to a user in Rails 5.2.

I have read many other posts, but do not see how they apply to this issue.

I tried

```
Listing.includes(listable:[:user]).where('users.id': 100)
```

But I get

> ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError (Cannot eagerly load the
>   polymorphic association :listable)

#### User Model

```
User has_one Car
User has_one Truck
User has_one Bike
```

#### Car Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_one  :listing, as: :listable
```

#### Truck Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_one  :listing, as: :listable
```

#### Bike Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_one  :listing, as: :listable
```

#### Listing Model

```
belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
```

Comment: @mrzasa, I saw that post, but do not think it solve the issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: @battleTested Please let me know what I am missing from the other post, as I do not seem to understand why people think this is a duplicate.