# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "listings")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

## Listing Model

```
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :car, -> { where(listings: {listable_type: 'Car'}) }, foreign_key: 'listable_id'

  def car
     return unless listable_type == "Car"
     super
  end



listing = Listing.first
listing.car
```

## Error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "listings") LINE 1: ....* FROM "cars"
>   WHERE "cars"."id" = $1 AND "listings"...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."id" = $1 AND
>   "listings"."listable_type" = $2 LIMIT $3

I also tried:

```
  belongs_to :car, -> {  joins(:listings).where(listings: {listable_type: 'Car'}) }, foreign_key: 'listable_id'
```

and I got:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Car' to association
>   named 'listings'; perhaps you misspelled it?)

What is causing this error?

Comment: rather than `super` just call `listable` this will return your `Car`. The belongs_to is wrong because the `where` clause applies to the `Car` model (thus the error). To solve that you would need to `join(:listings)` and drop the where I believe

Comment: @engineersmnky, Thank you! It's related to this question, in case it changes your answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209650/eager-load-relation

Comment: However you overlooked [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic#comment60786136_16124295) which suggests similar to what I have however it appears they recommend `-> { joins(:listings).where(listings: {listable_type: 'Car'}) }` which makes little sense to me because the join should already enforce that on a polymorph e.g. `INNER JOIN listings ON listings.listable_id = cars.id and listings.listable_type = 'Car'` So I am still not sure that is needed. I never use polymorphs in this fashion otherwise I would post an answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I tried your note, but got the above error too.  Thank you for trying. If you have other thoughts, please let me know. I am about ready to through my computer out the window

Comment: Well, Car has_one :listing, does anything need to be adapted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197060/discussion-between-user2012677-and-engineersmnky).