Can I get a ActiveStorage Attachment via a relation in one simple query?
Given the following relations:
class User
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  has_many_attached :files
end

I want to get the attachment by id, scoped on the current_user. A way to do this is as follows:
current_user.messages.joins(:files_attachments).where(active_storage_attachments: { blob_id: params[:id] }).first.files.find(params[:id])

I was wondering if there was a prettier way that's still efficient?
The main issue is that record is polymorphic, so this gives an error:
ActiveStorage::Attachment.includes(:record).where(messages: { user_id: current_user.id }).find_by(blob_id: params[:id] })

Users can have many messages, so this solution would be too inefficient:
ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record_type: "Message", record_id: current_user.messages.pluck(:id)).find_by(blob_id: params[:id] })


Is the problem prettyness or performance? Also please add what you expect the query to return. Right now it looks to me that you can just do Attachment.find(params[:id] and it would be basically equivalent.

That's a security issue, users can then fetch the attachments from other users by changing the param.

This is why I said, please add the requirements, what you are actually doing and what your problems are. Otherwise, it is very difficult to help you.

You should start by reading up on indirect associations. I also think you should really really not use has_many_attached :attachments as the naming just gets silly - attach the attachment to the attachements_attachements table sounds like something Monty Python would come up with if they programmed.

@SiimLiiser I thought that was clear from the first sentence; I want to get the attachment by id, scoped on the current_user. I'll add some extra info regardless.

@max Thanks I've changed the post to have nicer naming. I've clarified my post a bit more as well.

I guess you could consider this "prettier": ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(record_id: current_user.messages.select(:id), blob_id: params[:id])

To get an attachment by its id - blob_id scoped to only the current user (addressing security concerns), define a scope in the User model:
class User
  has_many :messages

  def find_attachment_by_blob_id(blob_id)
    ActiveStorage::Attachment
      .joins("INNER JOIN messages ON messages.id = active_storage_attachments.record_id AND active_storage_attachments.record_type = 'Message'")
      .where(messages: { user_id: id })
      .find_by(active_storage_attachments: { blob_id: blob_id })
  end
end

Then you can get the attachment by:
attachment = current_user.find_attachment_by_blob_id(params[:id])


This gives the error Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :record This can be solved by adding raw sql to the query, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic#comment23079640_16124295

Got you, modified my answer.

Even though it's not the simple query I was hoping for, I believe this is currently the only solution that requires only one query. Since I appreciate your effort, I've marked it as the solution.
